# Windows media player control not enabled in the active desginer VS 2015 Community

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015, axwindowsmediaplayer

I'm trying to load the WMP control into my WPF project using [this guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/windows/desktop/dd564585(v=vs.85).aspx).

When I try and do this, I get the following error message: `The following controls were successfully added to the toolbox but are not enabled in the active designer`.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community (Version 14.0.25431), and targeting .NET Framework 4.6.2. I've tried targeting old versions, as well as moving the DLL into my project folder and adding a reference from there with no luck.

Comment: That is a guide for Winforms, you have to use WindowsFormsHost in a WPF app.  Google "wpf embed wmp" for hits, the top ones are existing SO questions.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Hans told me, I was using a guide for Winforms. [This article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/using-windows-media-player-com-in-wpf/) shows you how to embed the Winforms control in WPF.